# Domain of function $f (x) = \log (px^3 + (p + q)x^2 + (q + r) x + r)$

Tags: functions

If $q^2 - 4 p r = 0$, $p > 0$, then find the domain of the function, 
$f (x) = \log (px^3 + (p + q)x^2 + (q + r) x + r)$

My approach

Let $T=px^3 + (p + q)x^2 + (q + r) x + r$, and $T>0$ 
$\frac{dT}{dx}=3px^2+2(p+q)x+(q+r)$

The discriminant is $4(p+q)^2-12p(q+r)$

$r=\frac{q^2}{4p}$

The discriminant is $4(p+q)^2-12p(q+\frac{q^2}{4p})$

Solving we get  $4(p+q)^2-3(4pq+q^2)$

$4p^2+4q^2+8pq-12pq-3q^2$
$(2p-q)^2$
Which is always positive, hence the function $f (x) = \log (px^3 + (p + q)x^2 + (q + r) x + r)$ is increasing, from here I am not able to approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that $T>0$ , is the only condition for this function to be defined. Now, factorise $T$ as,
$$T(x)= (x+1)(px^2+qx+r)$$
Now, it should be strictly positive for all $x$ in the domain of the function. Also, discriminant of this quadratic is zero, hence it has one repeated root.

Can you proceed now?

Answer (score 1):

It is $$(q,r)\in \mathbb{R^2}: x\ne -1$$ and $$(x+1)(x(px+q)+r)>0$$